# Selector error: Exception has occurred: AttributeError 'str' object has no attribute 'attrib'

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm trying to scrape the score of the third tennis match in the table on [this site](https://www.atptour.com/en/scores/archive/waikoloa/574/2000/results).

I need to parse a match score into individual set scores from this html element:

```
html = (
    '''
    <td class="day-table-score">
        <a data-override-transition="" data-ga-category="" data-ga-action="Click" data-ga-label="" data-use-ga="true" class="not-in-system">
            <!-- Determine set tie break score --> 76 <sup>8</sup>
            <!-- Determine set tie break score --> 61
        </a>
    </td>
    '''
)
```

To simulate the scraping of a `HtmlResponse` object I've used the following line for this post:

```
from scrapy.http.response.html import HtmlResponse

response = HtmlResponse("xyz", body=html, encoding="utf-8")
```

I can get the raw text string of the match score using this xpath:

```
response.xpath("normalize-space()").get()
```

However, it will be quite an extensive job to build a parser to account for the all the different versions of tiebreaks that exist in tennis. What would be much easier is to be able to identify a tiebreak score on the basis that it is always located in a superscript element. As sequence matters the best solution I could come up with was to loop through each line of text, determine whether the line was text or a `sup` tag and then assign it to a set score container. For this example let's assume it's a dictionary:

```
{"set_1_score": 76, "set_1_tiebreak_score": 8, "set_2_score": 61, "set_2_tiebreak_score": None}
```

As there will be a bit of additional complexity in this process to keep track of set numbers etc I've simplified the code down to just printing whether a line of text is in fact a `sup` tag. From looking at the `HtmlResponse` object I can see there's an `attrib` attribute which I think is what I need. However, I can't seem to access it. The following code:

```
text_lines = response.xpath("//text()")
for tl in text_lines:
    print(tl.attrib)
```

Gives the following error:

```
Exception has occurred: AttributeError
'str' object has no attribute 'attrib'
```

This is especially weird as when I run `type(tl)` it is actually a `Selector` object not a `str`.

Below is also a print of the details of the `tl` object:

```
special variables:
function variables:
class variables:
attrib: 'Traceback (most recent call last):\n  File "/Users/philipjoss/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2022.18.1/pythonFiles/lib/python/debugpy/_vendored/pydevd/_pydevd_bundle/pydevd_resolver.py", line 162, in _get_py_dictionary\n    def _get_py_dictionary(self, var, names=None, used___dict__=False):\n  File "/Users/<me>/opt/miniconda3/envs/capra/lib/python3.9/site-packages/parsel/selector.py", line 387, in attrib\n    @property\nAttributeError: \'str\' object has no attribute \'attrib\'\n'
namespaces: {'re': 'http://exslt.org/reg...xpressions', 'set': 'http://exslt.org/sets'}
response: None
root: '\n        '
text: 'Traceback (most recent call last):\n  File "/Users/<me>/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2022.18.1/pythonFiles/lib/python/debugpy/_vendored/pydevd/_pydevd_bundle/pydevd_resolver.py", line 162, in _get_py_dictionary\n    def _get_py_dictionary(self, var, names=None, used___dict__=False):\nAttributeError: text\n'
type: 'html'
_css2xpath: <bound method Selector._css2xpath of <Selector xpath='//text()' data='\n        '>>
_csstranslator: <parsel.csstranslator.HTMLTranslator object at 0x7fbfca5cf850>
_default_namespaces: {'re': 'http://exslt.org/reg...xpressions', 'set': 'http://exslt.org/sets'}
_default_type: None
_expr: '//text()'
_get_root: <bound method Selector._get_root of <Selector xpath='//text()' data='\n        '>>
_lxml_smart_strings: False
_parser: <class 'lxml.html.HTMLParser'>
_tostring_method: 'html'
```

I guess this is a two part question:

1. Why am I getting the error that I am? It looks like there might be an issue in the `parsel` package?
2. Is this the best way to cycle through the different lines of the text element to build the dictionary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you are getting the error is because when you use the `.../text()`
xpath selector, the return value might be a selector but the selector is just a
wrapper around the string extracted from the your query.  And plain text strings
do not have any attributes.

I think a similar but slightly better solution would be to simply test for the
existence of a `<sup>` element when you iterate through each selector that is a
direct child of the `td.day-table-score`.  If it is not a  tag, then you can
assume that it is plain text and assign it as the score of a new set, otherwise
you can assign it as the tie breaker for the previous set in a dictionary.

For example:

```
import scrapy

class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "myspider"
    start_urls = ["https://www.atptour.com/en/scores/archive/waikoloa/574/2000/results"]

    def parse(self, response):
        for tag in response.css("td.day-table-score a"):
            score = {}  # keeps track of score for this table row
            for elem in tag.xpath('./text()|sup'):   
                if elem.re('<sup>'):
                    val = elem.xpath('./text()').get().strip()
                    s = len(score)
                    score[f"set_{s}"]["tiebreaker"] = val
                else:
                    s = len(score) + 1
                    val = elem.get().strip()
                    if val:
                        score[f"set_{s}"] = {"score": val, "tiebreaker": None}
            yield score  # the final score collection
```

`OUTPUT`

```
{'set_1': {'score': '75', 'tiebreaker': None}, 'set_2': {'score': '62', 'tiebreaker': None}}
{'set_1': {'score': '46', 'tiebreaker': None}, 'set_2': {'score': '62', 'tiebreaker': None}, 'set_3': {'score': '64', 'tiebreaker': None}}
{'set_1': {'score': '76', 'tiebreaker': '8'}, 'set_2': {'score': '61', 'tiebreaker': None}}
{'set_1': {'score': '63', 'tiebreaker': None}, 'set_2': {'score': '75', 'tiebreaker': None}}
{'set_1': {'score': '61', 'tiebreaker': None}, 'set_2': {'score': '61', 'tiebreaker': None}}
{'set_1': {'score': '62', 'tiebreaker': None}, 'set_2': {'score': '64', 'tiebreaker': None}}
{'set_1': {'score': '76', 'tiebreaker': '1'}, 'set_2': {'score': '63', 'tiebreaker': None}}
{'set_1': {'score': '63', 'tiebreaker': None}, 'set_2': {'score': '64', 'tiebreaker': None}}
{'set_1': {'score': '62', 'tiebreaker': None}, 'set_2': {'score': '62', 'tiebreaker': None}}
{'set_1': {'score': '63', 'tiebreaker': None}, 'set_2': {'score': '67', 'tiebreaker': '2'}, 'set_3': {'score': '63', 'tiebreaker': None}}
{'set_1': {'score': '64', 'tiebreaker': None}, 'set_2': {'score': '64', 'tiebreaker': None}}
{'set_1': {'score': '64', 'tiebreaker': None}, 'set_2': {'score': '64', 'tiebreaker': None}}
{'set_1': {'score': '64', 'tiebreaker': None}, 'set_2': {'score': '62', 'tiebreaker': None}}
{'set_1': {'score': '64', 'tiebreaker': None}, 'set_2': {'score': '64', 'tiebreaker': None}}
{'set_1': {'score': '67', 'tiebreaker': '2'}, 'set_2': {'score': '62', 'tiebreaker': None}, 'set_3': {'score': '75', 'tiebreaker': None}}
{'set_1': {'score': '36', 'tiebreaker': None}, 'set_2': {'score': '76', 'tiebreaker': '5'}, 'set_3': {'score': '61', 'tiebreaker': None}}
{'set_1': {'score': '64', 'tiebreaker': None}, 'set_2': {'score': '63', 'tiebreaker': None}}
{'set_1': {'score': '61', 'tiebreaker': None}, 'set_2': {'score': '62', 'tiebreaker': None}}
{'set_1': {'score': '46', 'tiebreaker': None}, 'set_2': {'score': '76', 'tiebreaker': '10'}, 'set_3': {'score': '76', 'tiebreaker': '4'}}
{'set_1': {'score': '63', 'tiebreaker': None}, 'set_2': {'score': '64', 'tiebreaker': None}}
{'set_1': {'score': '64', 'tiebreaker': None}, 'set_2': {'score': '63', 'tiebreaker': None}}
{'set_1': {'score': '64', 'tiebreaker': None}, 'set_2': {'score': '62', 'tiebreaker': None}}
{'set_1': {'score': '60', 'tiebreaker': None}, 'set_2': {'score': '36', 'tiebreaker': None}, 'set_3': {'score': '64', 'tiebreaker': None}}
{'set_1': {'score': '75', 'tiebreaker': None}, 'set_2': {'score': '61', 'tiebreaker': None}}
{'set_1': {'score': '62', 'tiebreaker': None}, 'set_2': {'score': '62', 'tiebreaker': None}}
{'set_1': {'score': '61', 'tiebreaker': None}, 'set_2': {'score': '62', 'tiebreaker': None}}
```